# Find Peaks Of Data By Values And Sum Over Time Period In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

For a SQL query/stored procedure, I'm looking to find the sum of peak(s) of given values by type over a time period. Furthermore, if the peak doesn't have a downward trend during the given time period, it should not be counted.

The data, for example:

| Type | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 15 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 25 | 2021-07-11 *Need this peak |
| AAA | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 15 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 15 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 25 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 30 | 2021-07-11 *Need this peak added to previous peak |
| AAA | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 15 | 2021-07-11 |
| AAA | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| BBB | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| BBB | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| BBB | 30 | 2021-07-11 *Need this peak |
| BBB | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| BBB | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 30 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 10 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 20 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 30 | 2021-07-11 |
| CCC | 40 | 2021-07-11 *This peak won't count because the downtrend happens the next day |
| CCC | 30 | 2021-07-12 |
| CCC | 20 | 2021-07-12 |
| CCC | 10 | 2021-07-12 |

The results for given day 2021-07-11 should be:

| Type | Total |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 55 |
| BBB | 30 |

(CCC not included since there was no downtrend for the given date)

I'm not even really sure where to start except for maybe getting the value of each row that has a following row that is less (starts downtrending).

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without an ordering for the rows (perhaps using a time component on the `date`), the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that your `date` column has a time component to it.  You actually need an explicit ordering of the rows and the date is not sufficient.

If so, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by type, convert(date, date) order by date) as prev_amount,
             lead(amount) over (partition by type, convert(date, date) order by date) as next_amount
      from t
     ) t
where prev_amount < amount and amount > next_amount;
```

EDIT:

For the final agregation:

```
select type, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by type, convert(date, date) order by date) as prev_amount,
             lead(amount) over (partition by type, convert(date, date) order by date) as next_amount
      from t
     ) t
where prev_amount < amount and amount > next_amount;
group by type;
```

Comment: It is actually a timestamp, not just a date. Apologies, I was trying to simplify the example. I was wondering about using the lag and lead approach but wasn't certain. How can I make sure I'm getting each set (or each "Type" per example) and summing those qualified peaks?

Comment: Shouldn't the second comparison rather be `amount > next_amount` if we are looking for a local maximum?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this is very useful. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current table structure, this is impossible. You will need at least another column to indicate the order of each record. Otherwise a query won't guarantee

```
AAA 10  2021-07-11
```

will always come before

```
AAA 15  2021-07-11
```

There is no indicator why second is later than first.

Comment: There is no built-in ordering inside a relational data base - you must add it yourself in some way.

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. It is actually a timestamp, not just a date. I was trying to simplify the example but you're absolutely right.